# How do I write the negation of $\succsim$ without using txfonts or pxfonts packages?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

My problem is that I want to keep the original font and still use the negation off `\succsim`. I don't want to switch to `\nsucceq`. This is the symbol I want to write: [image: The sentence I want to write].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show the code you have tried so far? Then we have not to guess about documentclass and relevant packages you use ...

Answer (score 3):

You might use `\not\succsim`, but the slash doesn't combine too well. With an ordinary slash it seems a bit better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varnotsuccsim}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\varn@t\succsim}}
\newcommand{\varn@t}[2]{%
  \vphantom{/{#2}}%
  \ooalign{\hfil$\m@th#1/\mkern2mu$\cr\hfil$\m@th#1#2$\hfil\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\varnotsuccsim B$ \verb|\varnotsuccsim|

$A\not\succsim B$   \verb|\not\succsim|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much.

Comment: Nice! Do you know why sometimes `\not` does not combine too well? We are forcing to create a new command when, I think, `\not` should work.

Comment: @manooooh That much depends on the shape of the symbol to negate. Try the difference between `\notin` and `\not\in` with Computer Modern fonts.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well what you want, you can borrow only these symbols from the `mathabx` fonts without  having to load  the fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{%
  <-6> mathb5
  <6-7> mathb6 
  <7-8> mathb7
  <8-9> mathb8
  <9-10> mathb9 
  <10-12> mathb10 
  <12-> mathb12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\nprecsim}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"C2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nsuccsim}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"C3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\precnsim}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"C4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\succnsim}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"C5}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
a \nprecsim b \quad a \nsuccsim b \\
a \precnsim b\quad a \succnsim b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `cancel` package. You'll the be able using `$\cancel{\succsim}$`

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

    $\cancel{\succsim}$
    $\cancel{1234567890}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know they are logically equivallent, but I still would like to write the symbol $\succsim$ with a / across. I am typeseting a problem set and the author writes that way.

Comment: I edited my answer